# Cannot connect to mysql backend in airflow [airflow remains connected to default sqlite db]

Tags: python, airflow

I have changed below configs to connect airflow  to mysql database. But the airflow reamins connected to default sqlite database. Please see below config that I tried to connect to mysql db.

```
1)config of airflow.cfg:
executor = LocalExecutor
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql+pymysql://root:12345678@localhost:3306/airflow

2) pip install PyMySQL  (installed pyMysql package)

3)Installed mysql server in ubuntu machine where airflow is running

But when i run "airflow db init", It stills points to sqlite and no new tables are created in mysql db.

->airflow db init
o/p:
DB: sqlite:////root/airflow/airflow.db
[2022-01-29 11:04:32,833] {db.py:684} INFO - Creating tables

...
Initialization done


NOte:-
Above in output it still shows "DB: sqlite:////root/airflow/airflow.db"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set configuration options in various ways. From https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html (in this order):

1. set as an environment variable (AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN)
2. set as a command environment variable (AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN_CMD)
3. set as a secret environment variable (AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN_SECRET)
4. set in airflow.cfg
5. command in airflow.cfg
6. secret key in airflow.cfg
7. Airflow’s built in defaults

Since you say you've set it in `airflow.cfg`, I'm guessing `AIRFLOW_HOME` isn't configured, and it will assume your home directory for that. Are you running your Airflow in a different folder than your home directory? If so, you can configure `AIRFLOW_HOME=[your airflow project dir]` and it should pick up your `airflow.cfg`.

You can inspect the value of sql_alchemy_conn plus where it's configured in the Airflow UI -> Admin -> Configurations (requires `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG=True`). Scroll down past the default.cfg and the table shows each configuration's source.